# thoughts about antivirus dll

Tags: c#, antivirus, codeplex

Currently i've tried the antivirus dll from this site:
http://antivirusscanner.codeplex.com/documentation

After installing this package from nuget i ran the code to scan (and clean) a file. 
I got a 'virusnotfound' answer back, but that wasn't what i expected: I had no single antivirus program installed.

Does anyone know if this package contains some function to check if an antivirus program is installed? I want to know for sure if the code works fine.

Answer (score 1):

To be fair, the response it correct: it didn't *find* a virus. That doesn't say whether or not it had the tools to *look very hard*. There are only 3 responses:

- `VirusNotFound`
- `VirusFound`
- `FileNotExist`

of those, it sounds like `VirusNotFound` is the closest.

To check, you could perhaps use [EICAR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EICAR_test_file).

Comment: So if we decide to put the application on the server then it would be normal to say 'VirusNotFound' when there is no virusscanner installed? I think its not bugfree because no exception is thrown.